# Where is this method called - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

Im just starting to look at Open GL ES for iOS and I'm looking through the source code on apples template code. The problem is both

`- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect`

and

`- (void)update`

are being called, but I'm unable to determine by what and how to change the frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glkView is called automatically when the view needs to be updated.

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/GLKView) "A GLKView object uses the regular view drawing cycle for a UIView object, calling its drawRect: method whenever the contents of the view need to be updated."

You can use a GLKViewController to set the framerate of the glkview like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
}
```

Update is also called automatically for you before the rendering.  You can use this call to update variables such as the locations of your drawn objects - but you may want to use the timeSinceLastUpdate property because the time elapsed between calls can vary.